# Optimize mysql database performance

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, optimization

I have a database with some relatively small tables and one big table with about 10 million rows (11 columns) that I would like to optimize its performance. The table looks like this:

- Id: (int 11, primary key)
- Codigo: (longtext)
- Act_mas: (double)
- Act_menos: (double)
- Ind_mas: (double)
- Ind_menos: (double)
- Cap_mas: (double)
- Cap_menos: (double)
- Mensaje: (longtext)
- Fecha: (datetime)
- SuministrosId (int 11, this is a foreign key of a table with 62 rows, 21 columns that has another 2 foreign key, one with 44 rows and 11 columns and the other with 2 rows and 2 columns)

I guess I could change the datatype of `Codigo` and `Mensaje` to something like `VARCHAR(10)`, since normally the value has less than 10 characters and probably `LONGTEXT` is an overkill.

I could also change column datatype, from `Act_mas` to `Cap_menos`, to `INT`, since all the values should be smaller than 1.000.000 (at the moment the biggest value is 795.600, and it's very strange to have such a value).

The database and the table is using 'InnoDB' engine.

Actually a query like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE SuministrosId = 4 and Fecha >= "2015-01-01"` takes about 3-5 seconds to load. Maybe its not too much but I think it could be lot less.
I tried to change the datatype of some columns but it was terribly slow and I had to stop it, should I give another try? Also I added an index to `SuministrosId` but it seemed to be the same.

If other data is needed feel free to ask. Thank you in advance! (And sorry for my English :c)

**EDIT**

Computer info:

**CPU:** Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609 v4 @ 1.70 GHz

**RAM:** 32 GB

**OS:** Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

**MySQL Version: 5.7.11**

The database is used by an external java program that typically uses queries like the described above: `SELECT * FROM consumos WHERE SuministrosId = 4 and Fecha >= "2015-01-01"`, this is the most used query since it's the "core" for the job done here. Some other queries are used to list clients like: `SELECT * FROM clientes`, or `SELECT * FROM suministros`. But those tables are really small and they are not a problem.

**SHOW CREATE TABLE for the big one:**

```
CREATE TABLE `consumos` (
`Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Codigo` longtext NOT NULL,
`Act_mas` double NOT NULL,
`Act_menos` double NOT NULL,
`Ind_mas` double NOT NULL,
`Ind_menos` double NOT NULL,
`Cap_mas` double NOT NULL,
`Cap_menos` double NOT NULL,
`Mensaje` longtext NOT NULL,
`Fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
`SuministrosId` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
KEY `IX_FK_Contadorsuministrosset` (`SuministrosId`),
KEY `Fecha` (`Fecha`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_Contadorsuministrosset` FOREIGN KEY (`SuministrosId`) REFERENCES `suministros` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13002432 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Query explain: [image]

Profile:
[image]

Comment: Not really possible to answer unless you provide full index definitions, along with any exact performance issues you are currently hitting, along with explain plans for them

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table\G for all tables. Text of typical queries. Explain Plan for same. CPU, RAM, Storage (RAID config &c.), OS, would all be good for starters.

Comment: Is it really needed for all tables? I have 28 tables in this database, the biggest one is 11M rows, the second one 2,8M rows and the third 149k rows. Any way to get that info in just one query or do I need to run 28 querys? 
I'll add typical queries and server info on the first post. 
Finally, what do you mean with "Explain Plan"? I'm not really an expert of MySQL and databases, sorry :S and thank you for your help

Comment: @Vérace added some more info, tell me if you need something else.

Comment: Oh yeah - version of MySQL? Can you profile the consumos query?  HDD config? Put a `KEY` on Fecha and see does that help - I think it will. You appear to have two `KEY`s on  Id - if it's a `PK` it'll have one anyway. Same for SuministrosId if it's an `FK`, it's OK like that. Remove the extra ones! With 32GB of RAM, what happens if you run two queries (same) twice in a row?

Comment: @user3702623 Have you tried Partitioning the table on the dates. The example query you give might benefit a lot from partitioning. Also if you could provide some details on the existing indexes on the table it would be helpful.

Comment: @Vérace Version: 5.7.11. Added an Explain in the main post for the query. HDD config I'm not really sure, it's using Wamp in a 1TB HDD. There is another partition for data of 1TB too. 4 HDD, 2 mirror HDD.
Already added the KEY on Fecha but is pretty much the same (3.3 secs). 
If I run two queries twice its the same time, ~3.2 - 3.3 seconds.

Comment: @Punter015 how could I do that? You can see the SHOW CREATE TABLE at the main post. Do you need anything else?

Comment: @Vérace I've noticed that if I query: `SELECT * FROM consumos WHERE SuministrosId = 4 and Fecha > "2016-05-01"` it takes 5 seconds to load, but if I query: `SELECT * FROM consumos WHERE SuministrosId = 4 and Fecha > "2016-06-01"` (just changing months, may to june) it takes about 0.30 seconds. If I do an Explain of that, I notice that the second is using index condition, where and MRR. The first one is only using where. Why is that?

Comment: There is no way to "optimize database performance"; this is too broad.  It is often possible to "optimize one query".  So, let's see some slow queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That one query can be optimized with a composite index: `INDEX(SuministrosId, Fecha)`. Let's see some more. (Meanwhile, that pie chart is useless, it rarely says anything other than "sending data", and that gives no clues.)

Also, it may help to set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 20G *assuming you are using 64-bit OS and MySQL*.

Comment: Wow, this index helped a lot. Queries are taking now 0.003 seconds to load.
About the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` I had to set it at 3G, if I put more the server never starts don't know why.

Comment: Fixed, I was using 32 bits instead of 64.

Comment: With 32-bit MySQL, even 2G may be dangerously high.